using a .info file for tree where comment should be in the same line as file pattern
I know about the .info file functionality with the tree command and would like to use this in one of my bash scripts.
I played around in the terminal and have the following structure:
       test
         |-subdir
             |-A
             |-B
             |-C

and made the accoring .info by hand. It looks like this:
subdir/A
    comment for file A
subdir/B
    comment for file B
subdir/C
    comment for file C

and as expected the tree command lists the comments from the .info file as such:
[manoca@lumpy test]$ tree --info
.
└── subdir
    ├── A
    │    { comment for file A
    ├── B
    │    { comment for file B
    └── C
         { comment for file C

2 directories, 3 files

everything is fine. but now I need to put comment lines to the .info file automatically and would like to have the comment on the same line as the file pattern for easier parsing. Is this possible?
I tried to put the comment right next to the file pattern with a tab in between as the documentation for the info flag states:

If a file should match a pattern, the tab indented comment that follows the pattern is used as the file comment

So it looked like this:
subdir/A        comment for file A
subdir/B        comment for file B
subdir/C        comment for file C

But I guess "tab indented" means indented from the start of the line, as this .info does not work as intended and produces the following output:
.
└── subdir
    ├── A
    ├── B
    └── C

So my question is:
Is there a way to have the file pattern in the same line as the comment itself when using a .info file for the tree command?
Any hints are highly appreciated ;)

I don't imagine this would be possible. I mean, the documentation you quote is quite clear about the expected format, so why would you expect something else to also work? Have you seen anything that would imply that?

It was not that clear for me, as "tab indented" does for my part not clearly state "tab indented a the start of the line". Furthermore I felt like there is always a way in Linux ;) So my hope dies last I guess :) Plus it would make the changing of comments way easier for me, as I could work with simple sed commands to achieve this.

Oh no, sorry, I didn't mean to imply the wording is clear. It is not clear at all! But now that you've shown that it does indeed expect a tab indented line, given that this is what the docs say, I don't think there will be some secret implementation not mentioned in the documentation. I would instead focus on making the script that creates this file. I don't really see why it would be harder to have file_name\n\tcomment than it is to have file_name\comment.

I was hopin man could trick the machine with some semicolon shenanigans or other sort of stuff. For me it is way easier to work with single lines, as sed(my preferred search and replace tool) operates line-wise.

I would urge you to ask about that then. This really feels like an XY problem. Not only can sed handle this relatively easily, there are other, better and simpler tools you could use as well. Instead of focusing on changing the format that tree expects, just focus on the actual issue: that you want to automate this, and I am sure we can come up with easy solutions.

If you know of those "other, better and simpler tools " then why don't you just suggest one? btw: AWK is in my mind not simple in any shape, way or form. And all sed action with followin lines that I know of is not that standard as I'd like it to have.(e.g I know of problems with the 'c' command for example, which I'd use if I'd have to use sed to do this in a "proper" .info format. So what other tools do you know? maybe I'll find a good solution for my problem within your suggestions of alternative tools...

btw: I solved it with awk now, although I really wanted to use normal sed here(without 'next-line' shenanigangs). But it works now with this command:
awk -i inplace 'f{$0="\new comment for file A"; f=0} /subdir/A/{f=1} 1' .info

I would need to know exactly what you are trying to achieve, that's why I am suggesting another question. Sorry, I am really not trying to be difficult. I admit I find awk far simpler than sed, and I would probably use awk or perl here, but GNU sed can easily join two lines for processing. I tend to just use perl instead, but the sed isn't hard either. If you can show what input you will have and what output you would want, it is a simple text processing question.

No need for another question, as I solved it with awk now (see comment above). But thanks for reading and responding ;)
